# How to realize the mathematical sigma & pi notation in C#?

Tags: c#, math

**Sigma notation**: The summation of a sequence for i from n to m.

**Pi notation**:    The product of a sequence for i from n to m.

Comment: @HimBromBeere that post has been 2 years old and pretty dead as is. I understand this duplication mark, but it was nevertheless worth updating dead information.

Comment: Also, I don't get the PI duplicate? This post has nothing to do with pi.

Comment: 2 years old isn´t neccessarily "dead" nor "old", it´s still the exact same as now. Apart from this your question is really unspecific, doesn´t show any reaearch afford (**within the question**), nor is irt clear why the existing answers don´t satisfy your needs.

Comment: Related : [How to multiply all values in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132884/)

Comment: I think you should remove the part that is already address in the duplicate target. And use the duplicate target as a canvat to focus your question about "How to do the Foo notation in C#?" but with the Pov of someone that doesnt know the answer.  Here you almost no sentence nor context. If every information is in the title and you have to use the body as a place holder you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

## Summation Notation

The [Summation Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) can be understood as followed:

> In mathematics, summation is the addition of a sequence of any kind of numbers, called addends or summands; the result is their sum or total. Besides numbers, other types of values can be summed as well: functions, vectors, matrices, polynomials and, in general, elements of any types of mathematical objects on which an operation denoted "+" is defined.
>
> [...]
>
> Very often, the elements of a sequence are defined, through regular pattern, as a function of their place in the sequence. For simple patterns, summation of long sequences may be represented with most summands replaced by ellipses. For example, summation of the first 100 natural numbers may be written 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ⋅⋅⋅ + 99 + 100. Otherwise, summation is denoted by using Σ notation, where {\displaystyle \textstyle \sum } \textstyle\sum is an enlarged capital Greek letter sigma. For example, the sum of the first n natural integers is denoted {\displaystyle \textstyle \sum _{i=1}^{n}i.} {\displaystyle \textstyle \sum _{i=1}^{n}i.}

There are of course multiple options to realize this, however, the simplest and most forward option would be using the [`Enumerable Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netframework-4.7.2) as followed:

```
// Returns the sum
// for i from n (inclusive) to m (exclusive).
var sum = Enumerable.Range(n, m - n).Sum(i => i);

// Alternative
var sum = 0;
for (int i = n; i < m; i++){ sum += i; }
```

## Pi Notation

> [The Pi symbol, \prod, is a capital letter in the Greek alphabet call “Pi”, and corresponds to “P” in our alphabet. It is used in mathematics to represent the product (think of the starting sound of the word “product”: Pppi = Ppproduct) of a bunch of factors.](https://mathmaine.com/2018/03/04/pi-notation/)

This can only be solved a bit differently, since [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq) does not have any default algorithm for the pi notation ~ therefore, [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) is the way to go:

```
// Returns the product
// for 'i' from n (inclusive) to m (exclusive).
var product = Enumerable.Range(n, m - n).Aggregate((a, b) => a * b);

// Alternative
var product = 1;
for (int i = n; i < m; i++){ product *= i; }
```